# Puzzled by parametrized abstract types and covariance

Tags: scala, covariance, parametric-polymorphism

Consider the following Finagle service, which guarantees through the type system that a request results in a response of the correct type:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Service
import com.twitter.util.Future
import scala.language.higherKinds

sealed abstract class Request[+T] {
  type Response[X]
}

case class Enqueue[+T](value: T) extends Request[T] {
  case object OK
  override type Response[X] = OK.type
}

case object Dequeue extends Request[Nothing] {
  case class Value[+T](value: T)
  override type Response[X] = Value[X]
}

class Queue[T] extends Service[Request[T], Request[T]#Response[T]] {
  override def apply(request: Request[T]): Future[request.Response[T]] = ???
}
```

It would be nice if I could just say `Request[T]#Response` and `request.Response` instead of `Request[T]#Response[T]` and `request.Response[T]` in the last three lines.

My attempt was to add more indirection:

```
sealed abstract class Request[+T] {
  protected type response[+X]
  final type Response = response[T]
}
```

but this resulted in covariant type `T` appearing in invariant position.

Is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: It looks like request and response are intended to have different type arguments in the general case. If you want them to be the same, you do need to specify the same type twice.

Comment: @n.m. the intention is that the type argument to `request.Response`  where `request: Request[T]` is always `T`.

Comment: Is this your code? If you intend two arguments to always be the same, why are there two arguments in the first place? Canyou explain this design in plain language?

Comment: @n.m. because otherwise it would not be possible to override `Response` in `Dequeue` because the type argument to `Value` would not be known.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. It looks like you would be served by `Request[In, Out]`, without any parameterized type inside. Then `Enqueue[T] extends Request[T, Nothing]` and `Dequeue[T] extends Request[Nothing, T]`.

Comment: @n.m. what I want to accomplish is that the response type can be determined from the request type, since an `Enqueue` request will always return in an `OK.type` response and a `Dequeue` request will always result in a `Value` response. I want to enforce this in the type system.

Comment: So is there something particularly wrong with what I'm proposing?